# Set Visibility not working on Image View

Tags: java, android, android-studio, visibility

Why is my imageView not becoming visible with the checkingBalance = $1200 or more?

I have it set to invisible in the XML file. I essentially want the ivArrow ImageView to only appear visible IF my checkingBalance is over $1199.99.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView ivArrow;
    TextView tvCheckingBalance;
    TextView tvInvestmentsBalance;
    TextView tvPayRate;
    TextView tvToday;
    TextView tvWorkBalance;
    Button btnWork;

    boolean runInitialize = true;
    float checkingBalance;
    float investmentsBalance;
    float payRate;
    float workBalance;
    int today;
    int weekDay;
    int workPercent;

    DecimalFormat dollarFormat = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("com.vuvaia.lifeofme", MODE_PRIVATE);
        runInitialize = settings.getBoolean("runInitialize", runInitialize);

        if (runInitialize) {
            initialize();
            loadSettings();
        } else {
            loadSettings();
        }

        // INITIALIZING VIEW SETUP
        ivArrow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivArrow); 
        tvCheckingBalance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCheckingBalance);
        tvCheckingBalance.setText("$" + dollarFormat.format(checkingBalance));
        tvInvestmentsBalance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvInvestmentBalance);
        tvInvestmentsBalance.setText("$" + dollarFormat.format(investmentsBalance));
        tvPayRate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPayRate);
        tvPayRate.setText("$" + dollarFormat.format(payRate) + "/hr");
        tvToday = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvToday);
        tvToday.setText(String.valueOf(today));
        tvWorkBalance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvWorkBalance);
        tvWorkBalance.setText("$" + dollarFormat.format(workBalance));

        btnWork = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnWork);

        btnWork.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                workButtonPressed();
            }
        });

        // TODO SET UP THIS ARROW THAT TRANSFERS MONEY TO INVESTMENTS
        if(checkingBalance > 1199.99f) {
            ivArrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        loadSettings();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        saveSettings();
    }

    // WORK BUTTON PRESSED ACTIONS **************************************************
    public void workButtonPressed(){
        if(workPercent < 100){
            workBalance += (payRate * .4);
            tvWorkBalance.setText("$" + dollarFormat.format(workBalance));
            workPercent ++;
            advanceDays();
        } else {
            checkingBalance = checkingBalance + workBalance;
            tvCheckingBalance.setText("$" + dollarFormat.format(checkingBalance));
            workPercent = 0;
            workBalance = 0.0f;
            tvWorkBalance.setText("$" + dollarFormat.format(workBalance));
            today += 2;
            weekDay = 0;
            tvToday.setText(String.valueOf(today));
        }
    }
    // WORK BUTTON PRESSED ACTIONS **************************************************

    // ADVANCING THE CALENDAR DAYS **************************************************
    public void advanceDays(){
        if(weekDay <= 17){
            weekDay ++;
        } else {
            weekDay = 0;
            today ++;
            tvToday.setText(String.valueOf(today));
        }
    }
    // ADVANCING THE CALENDAR DAYS **************************************************

    // LOADING AND SAVING **************************************************
    public void initialize(){
        checkingBalance = 0.00f;
        investmentsBalance = 0.00f;
        payRate = 7.57f;
        today = 0;
        weekDay = 0;
        workBalance = 0.00f;
        workPercent = 0;

        saveSettings();
    }
    public void saveSettings(){
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("com.vuvaia.lifeofme", MODE_PRIVATE);
        settings.edit().putFloat("checkingBalance", checkingBalance).commit();
        settings.edit().putFloat("investmentsBalance", investmentsBalance).commit();
        settings.edit().putFloat("payRate", payRate).commit();
        settings.edit().putBoolean("runInitialize", false).commit();
        settings.edit().putInt("today", today).commit();
        settings.edit().putInt("weekDay", weekDay).commit();
        settings.edit().putFloat("workBalance", workBalance).commit();
        settings.edit().putInt("workPercent", workPercent).commit();
    }
    public void loadSettings(){
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("com.vuvaia.lifeofme", MODE_PRIVATE);
        checkingBalance = settings.getFloat("checkingBalance", checkingBalance);
        investmentsBalance = settings.getFloat("investmentsBalance", investmentsBalance);
        payRate = settings.getFloat("payRate", payRate);
        runInitialize = settings.getBoolean("runInitialize", runInitialize);
        today = settings.getInt("today", today);
        weekDay = settings.getInt("weekDay", weekDay);
        workBalance = settings.getFloat("workBalance", workBalance);
        workPercent = settings.getInt("workPercent", workPercent);
    }
    // LOADING AND SAVING **************************************************
}
```

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#EEEEEE"
    tools:context="com.vuvaia.lifeofme.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnWork"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:background="#2A2A2A"
        android:text="Work"
        android:textColor="#EEEEEE"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvWorkBalance"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#2A2A2A"
        android:textColor="#EEEEEE"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnWork"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPayRate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#2A2A2A"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvWorkBalance"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCheckingBalance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#2A2A2A"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvToday"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#2A2A2A"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvInvestmentBalance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#2A2A2A"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivArrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvCheckingBalance"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/tvCheckingBalance"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: first you should check the condition by providing Hard-Coded value for checkingBalance, If Condition  is ok then you have check the value which you are Assigning to checkingBalance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add *Visibility* code inside *onClick* of **btnWork**

```
btnWork.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            workButtonPressed();
           // TODO SET UP THIS ARROW THAT TRANSFERS MONEY TO INVESTMENTS

          if(checkingBalance > 1199.99f) {
              ivArrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          }
        }
    });
```

Comment: This more or less fixed the issue. I placed an If statement in the workButton listener which determined whether or not I had reached 1200.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly guess your **checkingBalance** having problem. Didn't return your expected value .

```
    float f1 = 1200;
    float f2 = 1199.99f;
    int compare = Float.compare(f1,f2);

    if(compare > 0){
        System.out.println("First is grater");
    }else if(compare < 0){
        System.out.println("Second is grater");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Both are equal");
    }
```